# Show different activities based on user choice in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

How can I set my app to behave in such a way that when user arrives on my app for the first time a page appears for them to choose their status?

E.g

Student
Teacher

What I want is for two buttons to appear on that first screen they will see on the app.

So if a user clicks Student, each time he/she opens that app he will always be directed to an activity I designed for just students e.g student_activity layout.

But if the student choose Teacher, each time the app runs it will take the user to teacher_activity layout.

I will be so much thankful to anyone that can provide me with  a good to set this on my app.

Plenty thanks as you look into it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use sharedPrefrences to store the user choice and then check the saved choice when your application is launched

create a SharedInfo class :

```
public class SharedInformation {

private Context context;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


public SharedInfo(Context c){


    
context = c;
    sharedPreferences =context.getSharedPreferences("login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

}

public void setusertype(String type){

    editor.putString("type",type);

    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}

public String getusertype(){

   return sharedPreferences.getString("type","");
}

public void clearinfo(){


    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

In your main/welcome activity:

```
SharedInfo sharedinfo = new SharedInfo(this);

if(sharedinfo.getusertype().isEmpty()){ //do nothing let the user pick a choice}

if(sharedinfo.getusertype().equals("student"){
//make an intent to send to student activity
}

if(sharedinfo.getusertype().equals("teacher"){
//make an intent to send to teacher activity
}

//etc
```

When the user picks a choice for the first time make sure to save it in your SharedInfo class like that :

```
sharedinfo.setusertype("yourtype");
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, I am getting joy as I am sure this will work, should I put the 2nd code block on my oncreate for the welcome activity?

Comment: Also is this all I have to implement, will the code popup a dialog on the welcome activity for user to pick if he/she is a student or on button click?

Comment: this is most of it yes , make the welcome activity completely separate from the other activities and display the choices there no need for a dialog, when the user picks a choice it will be saved and the app is launched again the welcome activity will send the user automatically towards their selection

Comment: Thank you so much for putting me through on this, should I add this line on the button click intent I create on welcome activity ?```sharedinfo.setusertype("yourtype");```

Comment: yes you need to add that to save the type , your welcome